# Bad day fixing references in mvc 5.1 app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-5.1

**I have a problem with visual studio and nuget package manger**

---

I was running very good when suddenly the project stopped to compile telling me that the ApplicationDbContext should derive from DbContext or something like that, i couldn't see the problem so i cleaned my solution rebuilt the project it compiled but had stupid runtime erros so I searched stackoverflow and the web And I found out it was a reference error in the first place so I removed the bin folder as described here in this question

[higher version than the referenced assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219832/error-cs1705-which-has-a-higher-version-than-referenced-assembly)

then it went all bad i tried to remove all the references and re-install them manually but nuget PMC kept telling me that my project already had a reference to that assembly,, I closed Visual Studio re-cleaned the project and done that once again with no results!

so the question here would be how to re-install the latest version of everything to be compatible with asp.net MVC 5.1 without getting a message telling me that my project has a reference to those assemblies nonsense !

Comment: Have you tried adding binding redirects to your web.config?

Comment: no, do I have to ? I mean why doesn't it work as its supposed to in the first place !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this happen to every one of my projects I upgraded to MVC 5.1. I had to add binding-redirects to my web.config. With the `Package Manager Console` it was easy.

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-manager-console-powershell-reference#Add-BindingRedirect